# Открыть файл как двоичный код

Tags: c++, qt, файлы, qt5, шифрование

Всем привет! Я пишу программу, которая осуществляет шифрование файлов и текста с помощью логических операций. А именно - *XOR*, *OR* и *AND*. Как известно, каждая из них имеет два аргумента, а на выход подается одно значение. Для этого при шифровании текста определяются двоичные коды символов, и эту часть программы я уже сделал. Но как открыть **файл** в виде последовательности нулей и единиц? Заранее всем благодарен.

P. S. Язык программирования - *С++*, использую *Qt*.

Comment: Смотрите на QDataStream

Comment: Работайте с битами вручную. Вычленяете AND-ом младший бит, затем сдвигаете всё число на один бит вправо. Повторяете это в цикле с количеством итераций, равным количеству бит в числе. Обработали очередное число — считываете из файла следующее. *Примечание: число может быть любым беззнаковым: `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`*.

Comment: Ответ на вопрос зависит от того, в каком виде вам нужны двоичные данные, то есть в каком виде вам удобнее работать с ними в той части кода, где вы выполняете шифрование. Самый простой способ - `QFile::readAll` - вернет вам `QByteArray` с двоичными данными, дальше можно его шифровать как нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    ifstream ifs("in.txt", ios::binary);
    if(!ifs) 
    {
        cerr << "File error." << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    //Твой код
    return 0;
}
```

`ios::binary` - открывает файл в бинарном виде.